# Feature-based malware detection

Tags: regression, data-visualization, data-mining, dataset

My aim is to detect a malware by testing it with the extracted features. I have extracted the binary features of 150 malware and 150 benign files by using the hex editor tool for unpacking the files and net beans for generating a dataset into an Excel sheet.

Now I have features of malware and benign datasets in separate sheets. Now I want to test a new file with the existing features to say whether it is a malware file or a benign file, for this I'm working with WEKA tool. can I achieve my goal with this tool? If not, Which tool is better for my project. I just want to compare the new file automatically with those two malware and benign datasets when given as input and should say if it is malware file or benign file.

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything domain-specific in Weka. If it implements an algorithm that you're interested in, then it's a very good place to start. However:

1. Putting your data into excel seems…unusual. If you're adding this on to an existing workflow, it *might* be tolerable, but if you're building this from scratch, almost any other solution would be less painless. Weka supports a CSV-like format called [ARFF](http://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF+%28stable+version%29) if you want flat text files. It also can also be coaxed into talking to databases.
2. It's not hard to find machine learning software that you can run over your data. The real trick is finding appropriate features that let that software distinguish between its classes.
3. There has been a fair amount of work on this problem already. This paper is eight years old, but may be a good start ([Kolter and Maloof, 2006](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume7/kolter06a/kolter06a.pdf)). Note that they use WEKA!